# Design pattern for switching between classes

Tags: design-patterns

Let's say I have these 4 classes:

```
class A {
  int i; 
}
class B { 
  int i; 
  bool b;
}
class C { 
  int i;
  enum e; 
}
class D { 
  int i;
  float f;
}
```

I want to show the properties of the classes in a datagrid. Something like this:

```
+----+------+---+---+-------+-----+
| id | type | i | b |   e   |  f  |
+----+------+---+---+-------+-----+
|  1 |   A  | 1 |   |       |     |
|  2 |   C  | 3 |   | Enum1 |     |
|  3 |   A  | 4 |   |       |     |
|  4 |   D  | 1 |   |       | 2.5 |
+----+------+---+---+-------+-----+
```

The cells of the 'type' column have to be a drop-down menu, so the type can be switched to another type.

What is a good design pattern to tackle this problem?

Of course I had some ideas (but I don't know which is best):
Derive A, B, C and D from a superclass S? Create an enum 'Type' with TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD in S, so I can use that for column 'type'?

Instead of deriving from a superclass, I could do a composition:
class E contains an interface I. A, B, C and D implement I. E has the enum 'Type' again, so when i switch enum-value, interface I becomes an object of another class.
Or should I skip this enum, and let column 'type' represent the class attached to interface I directly?

Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on requirements for your `DataGrid`. If you don't need to have all columns in every row then you may consider to use a **presenter** class (with `PresenterForA`, `PresenterForB` and so on). It'll expose a method `GetValueName()` (it'll return column name) and a method `GetValue()` (it'll return value itself, as `string`). It may even be an interface implemented through multiple inheritance (pretty similar to a common base class but clearer intent, IMO).

Comment: @Adriano Good, post as an answer!

Comment: @MikeStockdale it should be elaborated to be an answer, so far it's just an assertion with my opinion but no pro/cons discussion and/or examples!

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism can be applied here. We can consider two inheritance hierarchy - one for the class type info, the other for the actual class. Class having type info can be implemented as singleton as it is the same for all instances.

When the data is displayed in the grid, this design enables treating all classes seamlessly.

For the sake of simplicity, sample code shows implementation of only one class B.

```
interface ClassInfo {
    String getClassType();
    ArrayList<String> getPropertyNames();
    boolean hasProperty(String propertyName);
}

class BClassInfo implements ClassInfo {

    static ArrayList<String> propertyNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static BClassInfo instance = null;

    private BClassInfo() {
        propertyNames.add("i");
        propertyNames.add("b");
    }

    static public ClassInfo getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new BClassInfo();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public String getClassType() {
        return "B";
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> getPropertyNames() {
        return propertyNames;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasProperty(String propertyName) {
        return (propertyName.equals("i") || propertyName.equals("b"));
    }
}

abstract class SuperClass {
    public ClassInfo classInfo;

    abstract public String getValue(String propertyName);
}

class B extends SuperClass {
    int i;
    boolean b;

    public B() {
        classInfo = BClassInfo.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(String propertyName) {
        if (propertyName.equals("i") == true) {
            return Integer.toString(i);
        } else if (propertyName.equals("b") == true) {
            return Boolean.toString(b);
        }

        return "";
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B bClass = new B();
        // instances of other classes are created.

        ArrayList<String> bClassProperties = bClass.classInfo.getPropertyNames();
        // collect properties of other classes.

        HashSet<String> propertySet = new HashSet<String>();
        // Now put all the properties in a set so that duplicates are removed.

        ArrayList<SuperClass> data = new ArrayList<SuperClass>(); // data to display in the grid.

        // Display the column headers (property set values from propertySet)

        for (SuperClass superClass : data) {
            // display type of class from superClass.classInfo.getClassType()
            for (String propertyName : propertySet) {
                if (superClass.classInfo.hasProperty(propertyName) == true) {
                    // display value of property from superClass.getValue(propertyName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```